# toDoList Rest API: springBoot+H2+springSecutiry

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-boot, h2

I,m trying to do toDoList Rest API and have some problems with it.
Help me!

I decided to do multiuser project, separate users using basic auth of Spring Security. Here is my Entities: Task.java

```
@Entity
public class Task {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@NotNull
private String title;
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate date;
private boolean status;
@ManyToOne
private User user;

public Task() {};
+Getters and Setters

@Entity
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String username;
@JsonIgnore
private String password;
@JsonIgnore
private String[] roles;
public User() {};
+Getters and Setter;
```

Both entity interface extends CrudRepository. Task have @ManyToOne relationship to User.
Java helps me to create bd in h2 according to settings in application.properties

```
# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
# Datasource
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:./data/ToDoList
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

**Problem #1:** I can't open h2 console. All crud operations are working well, i tested it it Postman, but i want to have access to console.

Then i implement UserDetailService to grab users attributes:

```
@Component
public class DetailsService  implements UserDetailsService{
  @Autowired
  private UserRepository users;

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = users.findByUsername(username);
    if (user == null) {
      throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username + " was not found");
    }
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
        user.getUsername(),
        user.getPassword(),
        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(user.getRoles())
    );
  }
}
```

And configure WebSecurity:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Autowired
  private DetailsService userDetailsService;

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .httpBasic()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable();
  }
}
```

And here is **Problem #2**: how to take information about tasks of only one user?
In findAll method for example.

P.S. Sorry for my french *(c)*.

**UPD.** 
Try to grad User's data from SecurityContext. Create new file UserController. And that is works fine. Still have problems with access to H2 Console...

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository tasks;

    @GetMapping("/tasks")
    public List<Task> getAllTasks() {
        List<Task> allTasks = tasks.findAll();
        List<Task> userTasks = new ArrayList<>();
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        String username = ((UserDetails)principal).getUsername();
        for (Task t: allTasks) {
            if (t.getUser().getUsername().equals(username)) {
                userTasks.add(t);
            }
        }
        return userTasks;
    }
}
```

Comment: SecurityContext holds information about the currently logged user.

Comment: NiVer, thnks for your replay. I know that SecurityContext holds it. But how to write it in code?

Comment: How is your User defined?

Comment: NiVer, thanks, i solved it by adding controller.